# Mathematical conjectures on which applications depend

Tags: soft-question, big-list, conjectures, applied-mathematics

What are some examples of mathematical conjectures that applied mathematicians assume to be true in applications, despite it being unknown whether or not they are true?

Comment: What **precisely** do you mean by "being unknown whether or not they are true"?

Comment: @Somos As in, we do not have a valid proof or disproof of the conjecture.

Comment: Do physicists qualify as "applied mathematicians"? There are hundreds of unproved conjectures that physicists believe.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Eh, probably close enough, as you don't make hundreds of answers.

Comment: This is tangential to the question, but perhaps might be of interest: "[When were mathematical conjectures first formulated and communicated?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6957/606)."

Answer (score 79):

An important specific conjecture is that you cannot factor large integers fast. Many security systems for Internet and other transactions, depend on this.

Comment: Afaik, all (public key) cryptography algorithms boil down to some number theoretic conjecture. Not necessarily factoring large numbers, but something has to be assumed to be difficult.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think this is not true for [Merkel hash-based schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree): "the European Commission has recommended use of Merkle signature scheme for long term security protection against quantum computers."

Comment: It‘s Merkle by the way. No politics involved.

Comment: Isn't a Merkle tree just as secure as its underlying hash function?

Comment: How likely is it that this would be proven false, but those systems still being secure?

Comment: See P!=NP https://mathoverflow.net/a/291019/102169

Comment: Even if P!=NP, factoring isn't known to be NP-hard, so crypto based on it could still be vulnerable even if we can't tackle NP problems in polynomial time.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: The application where factoring difficulty matters is not related to hashing. It is related to mainly two things: 1. secretly passing encryption keys without a listener being able to know what either party is talking about (Diffie-Hellman key exchange) and 2. asymmetric encryption where you can expose one of your encryption keys to the public (the public key) yet nobody can crack the encrypted message without your secret private key

Comment: @PyRulez an efficient algorithm for factoring gives an (essentially) equally efficient algorithm for breaking RSA and Diffie Hellman key exchange. The only technicality that can salvage these systems is that the efficient algorithm may be efficient only in theory, but in practice be very slow for all inputs of less than astronomical size.

Answer (score 50):

It is an open problem to resolve a question formalized by G. Shephard in 1975:

> ***Q***. Can the surface of every
>   convex polyhedron be cut along edges and unfolded flat to one non-self-overlapping polygon in the plane?

It is usually called *Dürer's problem* because there is a sense
in which it goes back to Dürer. But I am not sure it is fair to call it
a "conjecture," one reason this is not an ideal answer to the posed query.

It is also a bit of a stretch to claim there is a direct ***application***.
But I did find a Ph.D. thesis in mechanical engineering that lamented, 
"there is no theorem or efficient algorithm that can tell if a given 3D shape is unfoldable [without overlap] or not." Despite Dürer's problem being unresolved,
any engineer or architect who wants to unfold a 3D shape—say, to punch it out of aluminum—breaks it into convex pieces (one piece if already convex), and easily edge-unfolds the pieces without overlap. The lack of a resolution to the open problem is no impediment to actually finding edge-unfoldings
in practice.

---

[image]

               

<sup>Fig. from [Geometric Folding Algorithms](http://www.gfalop.org/), p.299:
Soccer ball unfolding.</sup>

---

> J.O'Rourke, "Dürer's problem."
>   In Marjorie Senechal, editor, *Shaping Space: Exploring Polyhedra
>     in Nature, Art, and the Geometrical Imagination*, pages 77--86. Springer,
>     2013. ([Springer link](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387927138).)

Comment: @Somos: You are quoting PyRulez, not me. I think what s/he means is that it is unknown whether or not the conjecture is true or false, or the open problem is resolved positively or negatively. The latter is the situation for Dürer's problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I find it incredible that this is an open problem.

Comment: Some partial results are in this paper: http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Ununfoldable/paper.pdf

Comment: The paper Timothy cites proves that a particular *non-convex* polyhedron (a "spikey" tetrahedron) has no edge-unfolding that leads to a non-overlapping polygon in the plane. So it establishes that if the conjecture is true, it requires convexity.

Answer (score 39):

The use of [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for public-key encryption is widely believed to rely on the assumption that factoring is hard. Actually it relies on a **stronger** assumption than this, namely that the [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem) is hard.

The RSA problem is the following: given a semiprime $N = pq$ and an exponent $e$ such that $\gcd(e, \varphi(N)) = 1$, efficiently compute $e^{th}$ roots $\bmod N$. It is widely believed that the only way to do this is to compute $e^{-1} \bmod \varphi(N)$ where $\varphi(N) = N - p - q + 1$, and in turn it is widely believed that the only way to do this is to factor $N$ so as to compute $\varphi(N)$. However, strictly speaking both of these are conjectures which are independent of the conjecture that factoring is hard.

So it may be that factoring is hard but that the RSA problem is easy because there is some clever way to avoid these steps and solve the RSA problem without factoring $N$. Note also that we only need to factor semiprimes; it may also be that factoring is hard but that factoring semiprimes is easy.

Comment: The math in RSA works not just for products of two distinct primes, but for any product of distinct primes (a single prime would lead to a really silly cryptosystem). So if factoring integers that are products of two primes winds up being easy without making factoring of squarefree integers with $k$ prime factors for some $k > 2$ also easy, then RSA could be saved by using $k$ primes instead of 2 primes.  Admittedly, all known guidelines for avoiding easily cracked public keys in RSA would need to be adapted to products of $k$ primes. Someone should start working on that so we're ready.

Comment: See P!=NP https://mathoverflow.net/a/291019/102169

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic again but RSA is not "widely believed" to rely on this assumption, it is trivially proved to be broken if you have a fast factorization algorithm because then the private exponent d is easily calculated from the public key (n,e) using the exact same steps that the original issuer used, namely the extended Euclid's algorithm can be used to find d as the multiplicative inverse of e modulo φ(n) = φ(p)φ(q) = (p-1)(q-1), which is basically what you wrote, too. So, my point is that "reliance" is transitive here.

Answer (score 35):

The Miller-Rabin primality test works very well in practice as a *probabilistic* algorithm for finding "practical" (not provable) primes in cryptography, but the algorithm would become an efficient polynomial-time *deterministic* algorithm if the generalized Riemann hypothesis is true for all Dirichlet $L$-functions (well, maybe just for even characters is enough). In practice I don't think anybody in cryptography cares about GRH being true or not in order to be content using this primality test precisely because of the probabilistic version of it that does not depend on GRH, so this example might not strictly be an answer to the original question, but I think it is a good approximation to an answer.

Comment: In particular, the probabilistic test is as good as the deterministic for applications, since with enough tests you can make it so the probability of error is the same as the probability of the deterministic test giving the wrong answer due to hardware errors.

Comment: Is the deterministic Miller-Rabin test actually used in practice?

Comment: @Kimball no, the probabilistic test is what is used.

Comment: Relatedly, we could prove better running times for the original version of the AKS primality test if some conjecture about the distribution of Sophie Germain primes holds. I'm not sure if later versions of AKS "depend" on that conjecture.

Comment: @Kimball In practice the Miller test is significantly slower than APR-CL and ECPP, and the latter don't require the GRH.  This is not a complete surprise as ECPP and the Miller test are both $O(\log^{(4+\epsilon)}(n))$.  Other than simplicity and theory there isn't much reason for us to pine for this.  Later versions of AKS do not rely on Sophie-Germain primes -- both Pomerance/Lenstra and the much faster (non-randomized) Bernstein variants do not rely on this.  The original and updated versions all run in empirical $O(\log^{(6+\epsilon)}(n))$ time (very different constants though).

Answer (score 22):

Although we have a [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture) now, I suspect grocers had intuitively stacked oranges in the most efficient way prior to the proof of Kepler's conjecture.  I don't know for sure if any grocer was an applied mathematician.

https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn26041-proof-confirmed-of-400-year-old-fruit-stacking-problem/

Comment: Most likely they were aware of Gauss' partial result for lattices...

Comment: I love a problem I can relate to.  (I finally get why everyone seems so interested in sphere packing :)

Answer (score 20):

Navier Stokes equations are believed to be well-posed.

Comment: It would be best to cite the specific conjecture (instead of just stating it), and how it is used in applications.

Comment: Is this even true (as stated)? My impression is that many people believe that the N-S equations are _not_ necessarily well-posed and that they might blow up in finite time, but not for 'real-world' data.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Your point is exactly what i meant. The "applied mathematicians" believe that NS are well-posed for conditions that occur in applications.

Comment: The conjecture is that the strong (regular) solutions of the Navier Stokes equations are _globally_ well posed if the initial data have _finite energy_. Jean Leray constructed (1934) global weak solutions.  For the appropriate formulation see an article by C.Fefferman on the milennium problem [EXISTENCE  AND  SMOOTHNESS  OF  THE
NAVIER–STOKES  EQUATION](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf).  Although mathematicians seem to be more excited on the NS, more interesting and physically reliable are Euler equations of incompressible fluids..

Comment: I wonder if what people really believe in or rely on is something like, *CFD simulations are a reasonable approximation to reality*. Even if it turns out, mathematically, that NS has some pathological properties, it could turn out that nature doesn't quite obey NS after all. Nature could obey some well-behaved equations that are close to, but not exactly the same as, NS, and maybe CFD simulations are doing a good job of approximating the real equations.

Comment: I think NS is a good way to understand the underlying mathematical difficulties. We are yet not really able to handle real non-linearity. NS with small data or short time is more or less a perturbation of the linear case. Hence, I think it doesn't matter that much which (sufficiently difficult) system one investigates.

Comment: As far as Euler equations go, however, while they admit an easier calculation of a solution in some cases, those solutions can come with utterly nonphysical behavior, including admitting an infinite speed of sound for incompressible fluids and infinitely thin shocks (i.e., singularities/discontinuities) without the diffusive terms added by viscosity and thermal conductivity for inviscid, nonconductive fluids.  These can create stability problems in a large number of numerical approximation approaches when solving real-world problems using these equations.

Comment: There are definitely phenomena occurring in the real world that are outside the scope of Navier-Stokes. For instance, cavitation. Whether cavitation is ever linked to failure of Navier-Stokes is certainly an open question. If global existence for Navier-Stokes fails, there must be an infinite negative pressure. This might be suggestive, but nothing more.

Answer (score 14):

I think the biggest example is [$P \neq NP$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). Security experts routinely assume this to be true when designing security algorithms. The correct functioning of millions of machines depend on this.

I think its also the biggest example because if someone proves it false, then, depending on the details of the proof, the applications **literally stop performing their intended function** (or not, depending on the details of the proof).

Comment: I think you are confusing $P=NP$ with "we can efficiently solve all NP problems".

Comment: I second Carlo's comment. Just knowing that P=NP doesn't let us (for example) factor numbers effectively, for a variety of reasons. Among others, 1. the proof might not be constructive, so it doesn't give us a relevant algorithm, 2. the polynomial algorithm might have horrible constant which make it unusable in practice (that happened with AKS primality test, which, while polynomial time, is to this day too slow to be remotely efficient).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That's why I said "depending on the details of the proof".

Comment: Of course this is your question and your rules, but my understanding of how the question is posed is that all that should matter is the conjecture itself, not hypothetical means of its (dis)proofs. By themselves, P=NP and its negation have basically zero impact on security, for reasons in my other comment.

Comment: @Wojowu AKS can be used with numbers with thousands of decimal digits. sure, you are not going to find the biggest prime in this way but it **can** be 100% used for practical applications like generating RSA keys etc. So: I think you chose a bad example for a big constant algorithm...

Comment: @Bakuriu I have never heard of using AKS for generating RSA primes, to my knowledge probabilistic algorithms are used. Do you have a reference for AKS being used?

Comment: @Wojowu I have implemented AKS and used it on numbers from hundreds to 10k digits without many issues. It runs in the order of seconds to some minutes so it is **not** *impractical*, just slower. If you need such numbers for real-time encrypted sockets it's too slow, but it's fine for creating certificates/ssh keys (it could even take an hour it would not make much difference in that case).

Comment: @Bakuriu, you keep saying this, but you have never shared your results.  These numbers you give are wildly different than any other published results.  It is stunningly easy to write an incorrect AKS implementation that looks like it works, but isn't actually the AKS test.

Comment: @Bakuriu I haven't implemented it myself, but other people did and they have researched the real-time running time. I have found [this](http://probableprime.org/images/primality-times.png) plot, which indicates that even for a 100-digit prime the AKS running time gets into _hours_.

Comment: Using the AKS algorithm from the paper on a 1000 digit input, r ~ 11 million.  This means you loop 11 million times, each one doing a modular exponentiation on a degree-11-million polynomial.  With Bernstein's 4.1 variant there are fewer than 1 million loops, but we also have loads of upfront trial division and Fermat tests required.

Comment: @Wojowu most applied mathematicians do assume this though, which was sort of the point. It probably wouldn't immediatly break all security, but it *would at least* require cryptographers to redo and recheck all their algorithms (and rethink how to prove an algorithm secure).

Comment: What machine depends on $P \neq NP$ for its correct functioning? This sentence confuses me. The fact that these machines seem to work correctly would then prove the conjecture...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi for a security algorithm to work correctly, malicious agents mustn't have access to it. This *might* not be the case if $P=NP$.

Comment: The algorithm would "work" correctly, it would simply be easier to bypass...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi part of correction for these algorithms is not only the correct result, but also correct security properties.

Answer (score 13):

Many cryptographic protocols are based on the problem which seem to be hard. Among them [Discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and its variants ([Diffie–Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem), [Decisional Diffie–Hellman assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption), [Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECDLP)), [Quadratic residuosity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem), lattice problems ([Short integer solution problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer_solution_problem), [Shortest basis problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Shortest_basis_problem),...),...

Comment: In fact, essentially the only known encryption scheme that is [unconditionally secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional-security_(cryptography)) is the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). There are a few other cryptographic (but not encryption) primitives that don't rely on any unproven assumptions, such as [Shamir's secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) and [Carter-Wegman MACs](https://www.lysator.liu.se/~jc/mthesis/5_Unconditionally_secure_au.html)
 (when used with OTP). But those are still few and far between.

Answer (score 10):

[Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) needs quadratic nonresidue $n$ modulo prime $p$. If the extended Riemann hypothesis is true, then the first quadratic nonresidue $n_p$ is always less than $3(\log p)^2/2$ (Wedeniwski 2001) for $ p>3$. Under this assumption Tonelli–Shanks algorithm becomes polynomial. Probabilistic heuristics (presuming that each non-square integer has a 50-50 chance of being a quadratic residue) suggests that $n_p$ should have size $O( \log p )$. The best unconditional estimate (Burgess) is $n_p\ll p^\theta$ for any $\theta >1/4\sqrt e$.

See also extended discussion at [The least quadratic nonresidue, and the square root barrier.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/least-quadratic-nonresidue/)

Comment: Which part of this are applied mathematicians using?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good upper bound on $n_p$ means that in this application one can search for $n_p$ looking at $n=2,3,\ldots$

Comment: Sure, but why would an applied mathematician want to know the first quadratic nonresidue?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because it needed in Tonelli–Shanks algorithm.

Comment: OK, but what would an applied mathematician do with Tonelli-Shanks?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It depends on the definition of "applied mathematician".